# Formulas for Specific Capacitance Measures

Tags: filter, capacitance, charging, discharge, formula-derivation

I am designing a charging and discharging capacitor circuit for my power harvester.  What I am looking for is the time it charges and discharges respectively.  When I lookev over wikia and google.  All they mention is a rise until it can barely reach max and a sudden drop before it really hits bottom.

for Example:

Seconds:......1secs....2 secs.....3 secs....4 secs

Charge%:.......45%.......60%......75%.......93%

Discharge%:....55%......40%.....25%.........7%

etc...

And how will a C or L capacitance filter work?  And how does it affect the filtering?  Let me know if this is not a proper question.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am unsure as to what you want or need.

Comment: a formula pertaining to time and volume

Comment: The way in which you write down your question urges me to suggest to you that you might want to study some of the basics about electronics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html) website: -

[image]

This informs you that there is indeed a formula (an exponential formula) that governs how the voltage on a capacitor rises when injected with charge from a constant voltage supply fed via a resistor.

The magic number is ~0.63212. This number tells you that with a fixed voltage applied to a resistor in series with a capacitor, the voltage on the capacitor rises to 63.212% of the applied voltage in a time that equals R*C. For the next time period it closes the gap by another 63.212% and ad infinitum. [Here's](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-16/voltage-current-calculations/) possibly another useful site.

Get this inside your head and then come back and ask about the LC circuit because that is an order of magnitude more subtle and complex